# Window 7 does not have games listed in the add feature section

Tags: windows-7, windows, gaming

Windows 7 pro - I would like to activate games but games is not listed in the turn on & off features window.  How do I add the games?

Comment: Try running `sfc /scannow` in command prompt and see if it finds any issues. Afterwards check if the Games option is in Windows Features. It should be the first option.